# Tensorflow Lite on MLKit giving this error: : #vk Got 1 class(es) for output index 0, expected 2 according to the label map

Tags: java, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit

After adding metadata to my tflite file to use it in ML Kit, I get the error  `Calculator::Open() for node "ClassifierClientCalculator" failed: #vk Got 1 class(es) for output index 0, expected 2 according to the label map.`  I have edited the number of classes in the metadata as well as the number of classes in the label file, and I still get the same error. My model is a binary image classification model, so there should be 2 classes in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models#model-compatibility, the output should be (1 * 2) or (1 * 1 * 1 * 2) if the output contains two classes. Could you double check for your output layer?

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. It works perfectly now!

Comment: @bjthedj11 how did you change output dimensions?